# Are all finite groups Lie groups?

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, finite-groups, lie-groups

Is it possible to find an isomorphism from any finite group to a Lie group (which has manifold dimension 0 and equipped with the discrete topology)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, if you see a finite group as a $0$-dimensional manifold, then it is automatically a Lie group. And I will tell you more: it will be a *compact* Lie group!