# Why rotations with two angles in $3D$ do not form a group?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, rotations

Let us use any parametrization of  $3D$ rotations with three angles (e.g. Euler angles or yaw-pitch-roll), and throw away one of the angles (just assign it a fixed value).

Will the remaining set of transformation form a group? If yes — which? If no — why?

Follow up: the same question on more general Lie groups. What typically happens if we fix some of the parameters? In which cases does this result in getting a new group? If it doesn't — why?

**CLARIFICATION**

Just in case ⁠— I'm NOT asking why the new set of transformations is not $SO(3)$ anymore, that's pretty obvious. The question is: which group axioms are no longer satisfied? We clearly have a neutral element, and for each transformation there is an inverse. So what's wrong then?

Comment: Closure under the group operation doesn't hold. Apply two pitch-yaw operations in sequence, and you can get some roll (or some permutation of this statement is true). [BTW, given that there are only three group axioms, and associativity *has* to hold, because the restriction of an associative operation is always associative, this should not surprise you.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a mapping $K$ from $S^1 \times S^1 \times S^1$ to $SO(3)$, sending a pitch-yaw-roll triple to the corresponding rotation matrix. [There are actually many such mappings, depending on the order of roll, pitch, and yaw, but that doesn't matter for this answer, so I'm just going to call the mapping $K$.

OP seems initially to be asking "Can we look at
$$
H = \{ K(\alpha, \beta, 0) \mid \alpha, \beta \in S^1 \}
$$
and see whether it's a group?" OP observes that $H \ne SO(3)$, that

1. $I \in H$, and that
2. if $U = K(\alpha, \beta, 0) \in H$, then there's a matrix $V \in H$ such that $VU = I$,

so that $H$ appears to be a subgroup.

I personally believe that item 2 is false, but that's not really the main point. As @DougM observes in another answer, we can multiply two elements of $H$ to get a new element that's *not* in $H$, hence that $H$ is not closed under multipication.

OP seems to then shift the rules a bit, and ask about $P = K(\pi/2, 0, 0)$ and $R = K(0, \pi/2, 0)$ (I might have the numerical arguments or their order wrong, but that will prove to be irrelevant) and wonders about the subgroup $L$ generated by $P$ and $R$. That subgroup is, indeed, a subgroup (no surprise there!). But not every element of that subgroup is in $H$, so it doesn't really consist of things "with the third parameter held to some constant".

One could go even further, and write $P(\alpha) = K(\alpha, 0 , 0)$ and $R(\beta) = K(0, \beta, 0)$, and look at the group generated by the image of the functions $P$ and $R$, i.e., all possible sequences of pitches and rolls through any possible angles. That turns out, by a small generalization of @DougM's answer, to be all of $SO(3)$.

Short summary: *if you parameterize a group $G$ by another group $H$, but the parameterization $K$ is not a homomorphism, then you should not generally expect the images of subgroups of $H$ under the map $K$ to be interesting.*

Comment: Thanks! It took me some time to realize that by taking all the possible sequences of parameterized group elements (with possibly restricted parameters) we cannot obtain anything interesting, since we shall always end up with some element of the original group. Correct for an arbitrary Lie group??

Comment: No, I think you have it exactly wrong. :)  If you take all possible sequences of "tilt" and "roll", for instances, you can generate "spin" (See @DougM's answer, for instance) and from that, you can generate all of $SO(3)$. What I'm saying is that if you look at $Q = K(S^1 \times S^1) \subset SO(3)$, and then look at the subgroup generated by the uncountably infinite set $Q$, you get all of $SO(3)$, even though $Q$ itself is a proper subset of $SO(3)$.

Comment: No, no, by "original group" I meant $SO(3)$ :)

Comment: As for "arbitrary Lie group"....I can't really say, because I don't understand what you're asking. But I can say this: If $Q$ is *any* subset of a Lie group $G$, and you look at the subgroup $J$ generated by $Q$ (essentially all finite products of elements of $Q$ and their inverses), then $J$ will be a subgroup of $G$ because of the definition of "product" and "inverse": these are functions whose codomain is $G$.

Comment: Yes, this answers my question. So, for Lie groups there is no analogue of infinitely-generated finite groups?

Comment: What? Every finite group *is* in fact the underlying group of a Lie group; you put the discrete topology on it, and it becomes a $0$-dimensional Lie group. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3158301/are-all-finite-groups-lie-groups#:~:text=Yes%2C%20if%20you%20see%20a,be%20a%20compact%20Lie%20group!

Comment: I meant infinite sequences of continuously-parametrized elements.

Answer (score 1):

Let consider some 90 degree rotations.

We have two rotation matrices that generate our group.

$P=\pmatrix{&1&\\-1&&\\&&1}$ and $R=\pmatrix{1&&\\&&1\\&-1&}$

Traditionally our third rotation matrix

$Y=\pmatrix{&&1\\&1&\\-1&&}$ has been left out.

But $PRP^{-1} = Y$

Two rotations will generate the 3rd rotation and hence $SO_3$

Comment: But why do we have to define '$Y$'? Instead, we can deal with a finitely-generated group generated by $P$ and $R$.

Comment: Or probably it would be an infinite non-abelian group.